# Agile Kanban sprints

Tags: agile, kanban, scrum-master

I wanted to know if Kanban follows sprints?

Are there live open Kanban dashboards that I can use to learn from?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sprints aren't a feature of the Kanban method because Kanban is all about managing continuous flow rather than delivery in fixed iterations. It is possible to use some of the techniques of Kanban along with other ideas from Scrum however. Such combinations are referred to as ScrumBan.

If you'd like to see examples of Kanban in action, check out [Featureban](https://tools.flowfast.io/featureban/), which simulates working with some example Kanban boards. It works best if you try it with multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kanban can be used in conjunction with sprints as it is a flexible method that can be adapted to fit different project needs. Kanban allows you to visualize and track your work as it moves through the development process, and many teams find it helpful to use it alongside sprints to better manage their workflow.

If you're interested in learning more about Kanban and how it can be used in your team, you might want to check out this on a [Kanban software](https://creately.com/lp/kanban-software/). It offers a range of tools and resources that can help you get started with Kanban, including live open Kanban dashboards that you can use to see how it works in practice.